# How to get the complementary values for a Delphi sets type variable?

Tags: delphi, set, delphi-2007

Starting from a set type variable like [`TAnchors`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TAnchors.html):

```
  TAnchorKind = (akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom);
  TAnchors = set of TAnchorKind;
```

I'm trying to get the complementary values.

```
var
  Tmp : TAnchors;
begin
  Tmp := [akLeft];
   ...
end;
```

I'm expecting to get all values of `TAnchors` which are not in the `Tmp` variable.

For example, starting from `[akLeft]`, I'm expecting to get `[akTop, akRight, akBottom]`.

I've tried using the `not` operator but it seems it doesn't work for [`Sets types`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)).

Comment: What about `[akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom] - Tmp`?

Comment: Alternativly you can also write: `AnchorAlign[alClient] - Tmp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set operators are listed in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Set_Operators). The `not` operator is not listed here which is why it cannot be used on a set. However, you are looking for the difference operator, `-`. Take the difference between the set including all members, and your set:

```
[Low(TAnchorKind)..High(TAnchorKind)] - Anchors
```